# Why does sed command output "char 5: unterminated `s' command"

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

I ran some command as below to debug my script but it was not work.

```
$ L="Thanh,Fri 11 Nov, Mon 14 Nov,LX,VN" 
$ B="Fri 11 Nov, Mon 14 Nov"
$ N="11.11-14.11"
$ sed 's/'$B'/'$N'/' <<< $L
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the unquoted whitespace in the expansion of `$B` - as you can verify using `set -x` in the shell:

```
$ set -x
$ sed 's/'$B'/'$N'/' <<< $L
+ sed s/Fri 11 Nov, Mon 14 Nov/11.11-14.11/
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command
$ set +x
```

(notice how sed receives separate arguments `s/Fri` `11` `Nov,` etc).

You can use

```
sed 's/'"$B"'/'"$N"'/' <<< "$L"
```

or more simply

```
sed "s/$B/$N/" <<< "$L"
```

ex.

```
$ set -x
$ sed "s/$B/$N/" <<< "$L"
+ sed 's/Fri 11 Nov, Mon 14 Nov/11.11-14.11/'
Thanh,11.11-14.11,LX,VN
$ set +x
```

Comment: thank a lot,
I got it.